# Why is it not matching?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code:

```
(SELECT 
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName],
[LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo],
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2] AS StdCost,
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[Price],
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID],
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
FROM 
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory]
Inner JOIN
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail] ON [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID] = [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
INNER JOIN 
[LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts] ON [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName] like [LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo]
WHERE ([QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[AccountRef_FullName] = 'Inventory, Raw Material')
```

I added unneeded selects to create the screenshot below of sample results.

[image]

```
ListID is varchar(255), null)
IDKEY is varchar(255), null)
```

Questions:

What would cause query to not see `ListID = IDKEY` for the `NULL` results?

EDIT Goal:

`Stdcost` should match the `Price` amount if `ListID=IDKEY` and `FullName=PartNo`

Comment: `null` is not equal to anything, including another `null`.  You must use the operator `is` for comparisons to `null`'.

Comment: fullname to Partno = has no nulls. they match.

ListID to IDKEY = has no nulls, they match.

Price has an amount is listed as NULL for it in StdCost.

Comment: isn't what you want an outer join?

Comment: Also you really should read about aliases. Your queries would be a LOT easier to read. Not to mention that three and four part naming is deprecated in the column list.

Comment: StdCost is NULL in table [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory; this is not a join issue. For a real answer, provide table structure and sample data that reproduces the issue

Comment: sean, stdcost should be a copy of price if listid=idkey

Comment: What is complicated?  `[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2]` is `NULL` in some rows.

Comment: like "ISNULL([QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2],[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[Price]) AS StdCost"? Your question is not very clear to me

Comment: Sean, I am trying to do this:   Stdcost should match the Price amount if ListID=IDKEY and FullName=PartNo

Comment: "stdcost should be a copy of price if listid=idkey"   What makes you think that?   You haven't coded it that way, so why should it happen that way?

Comment: You want LEFT JOIN not Inner joins.  INNER joins may remove data you want to keep - in this case especially.  Also LIKE without wildcards is a bit useless.

Comment: ***You said, "Stdcost should match the Price amount if ListID=IDKEY and FullName=PartNo"***  so... `coalesce( [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2], [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[Price]) as stdCost`  will set stdCost to the price when CustomField2 is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, you need to have the price returned if CustomField2 is null. This can be done with either ISNULL or COALESCE. ISNULL will return the second value if the first value is null.

```
(SELECT 
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName],
[LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo],
ISNULL([QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2],[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[Price]) AS StdCost,
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[Price],
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID],
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
FROM 
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory]
Inner JOIN
[QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail] ON [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID] = [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
INNER JOIN 
[LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts] ON [QBDATABASE].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName] like [LotTracker].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo]
WHERE ([QBDATABASE].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[AccountRef_FullName] = 'Inventory, Raw Material')
```

Comment: why not `case when ListID=IDKEY and FullName=PartNo then Price else CustomField2 end as StdCost`  though this is a very odd requirement.

Comment: @xQbert I took their comments to mean that when the value is null, they wanted price because otherwise CustomField2 should never even be referenced as the inner joins for that logic condition will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but too long for a comment. Here your exact same query. The ONLY changes I made was a little formatting and removed all those horrifically long object names and used aliases instead.

```
SELECT 
    ini.FullName,
    p.PartNo,
    ini.CustomField2 AS StdCost,
    spd.Price,
    ini.ListID,
    spd.IDKEY
FROM QBDATABASE.dbo.itemnoninventory ini
Inner JOIN QBDATABASE.dbo.salesorpurchasedetail spd ON ini.ListID = spd.IDKEY
INNER JOIN  LotTracker.dbo.tblParts p ON ini.FullName like p.PartNo
WHERE spd.AccountRef_FullName = 'Inventory, Raw Material'
```

The answer to your question is that the row in itemnoninventory contain NULL so of course it will be NULL in the query.

Comment: looks like they want a case statement in the join judging from the last comment *Stdcost should match the Price amount if ListID=IDKEY and FullName=PartNo* but i'm confused as usual lol

Comment: @scsimon hard to say....seems to be another question where I didn't bring the crystal ball. Do you happen to know where it went or who has it this week?

Comment: Indiana returned it to the alien's neck who then took it home.

Comment: Back to Area 52 again? So hard to infiltrate that facility, not sure I am up for another raid this year.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot upvote. I combined both seans replies and have what I wanted. Ty both.

```
SELECT 
    ini.FullName,
    p.PartNo,
    ISNULL(ini.CustomField2,spd.Price) AS StdCost,
    spd.Price,
    ini.ListID,
    spd.IDKEY
FROM QBDATABASE.dbo.itemnoninventory ini
Inner JOIN QBDATABASE.dbo.salesorpurchasedetail spd ON ini.ListID = spd.IDKEY
INNER JOIN  LotTracker.dbo.tblParts p ON ini.FullName like p.PartNo
WHERE spd.AccountRef_FullName = 'Inventory, Raw Material'
```